# How much memory do we have to set for JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh

Tags: java, tomcat6, heap-memory, catalina

Following are my system configuration

```
java version "1.6.0_17"  
Tomcat 6.0.18  
OS : Cent OS 5.7
```

[image]

Following is my JAVA_OPTS in Catalina.sh

> JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server
>   -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

I am getting the following error on heavy usage.  And the Tomcat Crashes..

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at org.htmlparser.parserHelper.TagParser.checkFinishedState(TagParser.java:157)
    at org.htmlparser.parserHelper.TagParser.automataInput(TagParser.java:93)
    at org.htmlparser.parserHelper.TagParser.find(TagParser.java:76)
    at org.htmlparser.tags.Tag.find(Tag.java:192)
```

Can any one please say the correct configuration for JAVA_OPTS so that I will not get this error.  Please help me Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**
Finally I gave the java opts as like this

> JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server
>   -Xms1536m -Xmx3072m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

Comment: Erm ... as much as your application(s) need.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly that is I have to give the maximum my CPU can hold.  Because this it the only site running in my server.

Comment: no one can tell you that. Your application is using all available memory. Either it's a bug, or you need to increase the amount of memory available to the JVM.

Comment: Ok..  I will try increasing the memory in my JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVM memory tuning is not an easy task.

Increasing JVM memory is the first thing you should do, but also take a look at some tools for investigating JVM memory consumption. You might start with jvisualvm or jconsole (both should be placed in ${JDK_HOME}/bin).

Comment: I made it as Xmx3072m now it is not crashing..  I dont know how to profile..  I am hitting the maximum file opening in linux and the application hangs..."Nb of opened files 122 / 1,024".. Do you have any idea how to find file leaks and stop it.  I got the above reading from Java Melody.

Comment: Hi Dilip, if number of opened files is the problem, you might increase it - take a look at this article: http://lj4newbies.blogspot.com/2007/04/too-many-open-files.html

Comment: WOW great.. Thank you very much altanis..  I will do this..  Is this anything to do with my code...that is do I have any coding issue to fix..

Comment: @altanis if i want to analyze it on unix server how can i do it? Because actual load is available on unix server only where lot of users are connected.